# Find just the un-matching id's from two list of the same objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to create a list of ids from two lists of objects that don't match the ids

I can do it the old way but want this to be done using java 8

This is what I have done and that works. (actual code providing this for context)

```
private List<String> getCartItemAttributesIds(List<CartItemAttribute> existingAttributes, List<CartItemAttribute> requestingAttributes) {
        List<String> attributeIdsNeededtoDeleted = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean flag = true;
        for(CartItemAttribute existingAttribute: existingAttributes) {
            flag = true;
            for(CartItemAttribute requestingAttribute:requestingAttributes) {
                if(StringUtils.isBlank(requestingAttribute.getCartItemAttributeId())) { 
                    flag = false;
                    break; 

                } else if (requestingAttribute.getCartItemAttributeId().equals(existingAttribute.getCartItemAttributeId())) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag) {
                attributeIdsNeededtoDeleted.add(existingAttribute.getCartItemAttributeId());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("*********************************");
        for (String var: attributeIdsNeededtoDeleted) {
            System.out.println("[" +var +"]");
        }

        return attributeIdsNeededtoDeleted;

    }
```

```
class Person {
    String id ;
    String name;
    String age;
}
p1:{1,test1,3}
p11:{12,test4,9} <----
p2:{2,test2,6}
p3:{6,test3,8} <----
p4:{1,test1,33}
p5:{2,test22,16}
p6:{3,test3,18}
p10:{null,test10,8}

List<Person> list1 = {p1,p2, p3,p11};
List<Person> list2 = {p4,p5, p6, p10};
```

results

```
list<string> results = {"p11","p3"}
```

**deatil explaination about the result**:

```
p1:{1,test1,3}
p4:{1,test1,33}
p2:{2,test2,6}
p5:{2,test22,16}
```

p1 and p4,
p2 and p5

their id matches even though the data doesn't but i don't want this id in the result

```
p6:{3,test3,18}
p10:{null,test10,8}
```

p6 and p10 are not matching but they are both in list 2 so don't want them in my result list.

```
p11:{12,test4,9} <----
p3:{6,test3,8} <----
```

p11 and p3. ids are in list1 and not in list2 so they don't match and should be in result list.

I want to use stream. And the model hash code has all fields in it and 'contain' or 'set' will think they are different objects. But for  my purpose only no matching ids will make it different.

Comment: Transform your first List into a Set<ID>. Do the same with the second list. Call set1.removeAll(set2). Done.

Comment: "*I can do it the old way but want this to be done using java 8*" - This is already valid in Java 8. What do you want to do differently?

Comment: What does CartItemAttribute have to do with Person? Please clarify your question (give clear reasoning as to why your output matches your input & specify exactly what it is that you want to do) and provide a [reprex].

Comment: sorry I meant to say using stream and filter and what not or if there are a better way of doing it.
set will not work as the model has is checking all fields. i care only about id. other things even if they don't match i don't want to pick it.

Comment: That's why you should transform your list into a Set<String>, containing the IDs of the objects of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `Set` class as suggested you can do it like this.  I added a extra field to the `Person` class as well as the `equals`and `hashCode` implementations.  But there is nothing wrong with what you are doing now.  Imho, `streams` are to make your coding easier, not force a particular implementation technique upon you.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Person p1 = new Person("1", "test1", "3", "p1");
      Person p11 = new Person("12", "test4", "9", "p11");
      Person p2 = new Person("2", "test2", "6", "p2");
      Person p3 = new Person("6", "test3", "8", "p3");
      Person p4 = new Person("1", "test1", "33", "p4");
      Person p5 = new Person("2", "test22", "16", "p5");
      Person p6 = new Person("3", "test3", "18", "p6");
      Person p10 = new Person(null, "test10", "8", "p10");

      List<Person> list1 = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p11);
      List<Person> list2 = Arrays.asList(p4, p5, p6, p10);

      List<Person> result =
            list1.stream().filter(n -> !list2.contains(n)).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(result);

   }

}

class Person {
   String id;
   String name;
   String age;
   String fieldName;

   public int hashCode() {
      return id.hashCode();
   }
   public boolean equals(Object ob) {
      if (ob == this) {
         return true;
      }
      if (!(ob instanceof Person)) {
         return false;
      }

      Person p = (Person) ob;
      if (p.id == null && id == null) {
         return true;
      }
      if (p.id == null || id == null) {
         return false;
      }
      return id.equals(p.id);
   }
   public Person(String id, String name, String age, String fieldName) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.fieldName = fieldName;
   }
   public String toString() {
      return fieldName;
   }
}
```

For completion, here is the Set solution that was mentioned in the comments.

```java
      Set<Person> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
      set1.removeAll(list2);
      System.out.println(set1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The functional calls on the stream can be made simpler by overriding the equals method to compare the id attribute in the `Person` class (as the other answer from WSJ shows). However, if equals() cannot be overridden like that, the full solution in terms of functional programming would be as follows:

```
private static List<String> filter(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
    return list1.stream()
            .map(Person::getId)
            .filter( id -> id != null && list2.stream()
                    .map(Person::getId)
                    .noneMatch( list2Id -> list2Id != null && list2Id.equals(id) )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You should prefer noneMatch() over .filter().findAny().isEmpty(). And it would be more efficient (and simpler) to make a Set of IDs out of the second collection first, to make it O(n) instead of O(n^2).